# Reduce Code Duplication Class Design

Tags: python, oop

I have a class:

```
class HolderClass(object):

    def __init__(self, list_of_objs):
        self.my_objects = list_of_objs

    def do_stuff(self):
        for item in self.my_objects:
            print item.a

    #more methods like this...
```

The objects in the `self.my_objects` list are defined by a single class. This class has several instance variables. What I would like to do is avoid code duplication but allow myself to perform the exact same calculations specifying a different instance variable.

So instead of writing another method like this:

```
    def do_stuff_on_b(self):
        for item in self.my_objects:
            print item.b
```

I'd like to be able to just re-use the `do_stuff` method but specifying a different instance variable. Is there an elegant way of implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, pass in the name of the attribute, then use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get it from the individual instances:

```
def do_stuff(self, attr):
    for item in self._my_objects:
        print getattr(item, attr)
```

Calling this with `self.do_stuff('b')` will print the `b` attribute on all items listed in `self.my_objects`

From the function documentation:

> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.